# Find objects in deep Mongo DB docs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a Mongo DB doc with a teams array. All the objects in the teams array contain a user_ids array. How do I find all documents containing a team where user_ids contains a specific Object Id? I'm using Mongoose with Node.

This is the doc structure. How would I eg find all docs with Object Id "56a60da2351195cc6be83799" in any of the teams?

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56a60da3351195cc6be8379c"),
"session_id" : ObjectId("56a60da2351195cc6be83798"),
"teams" : [ 
    {
        "score" : 0,
        "user_ids" : [ 
            ObjectId("56a60da2351195cc6be83799")
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "score" : 0,
        "user_ids" : [ 
            ObjectId("56a60da2351195cc6be8379a")
        ]
    }
],
"created_at" : ISODate("2016-01-25T11:57:23.006Z") }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your collection name is `collection`, try:

```
db.collection.find({"teams.user_ids": ObjectId("56a60da2351195cc6be83799")})
```

It will find a document, if exists matching `user_ids`

Comment: Amazing thanks! How about updating that id? For normal arrays I can do { $set: { user_ids.$ : XXX } }. That doesn't work with two levels. Any idea?

Comment: MongoDB does struggle with nested arrays, however you can easily update do so on client side.

Answer (score 0):

For nested arrays the $in operator will be a good choice (see [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)).

I tried to reproduce your settings and created a simple model:

```
var testSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  session_id: { type: Number },
  teams : [
    {
      score: { type: Number },
      user_ids: [{ type: Number }]
    }
  ]
})

var Test = mongoose.model("Test", testSchema);
```

Inserted demo data:

```
var test1 = new Test({
  session_id: 5,
  teams: [
    { score: 5, user_ids: [ 1, 2, 4] },
    { score: 3, user_ids: [ 2, 7, 9 ] },
    { score: 1, user_ids: [ 3 ] },
  ]
});

test1.save(function(err, t1) { console.log("test", err, t1); });

var test2 = new Test({
  session_id: 1,
  teams: [
    { score: 5, user_ids: [ 11, 12 ] },
    { score: 3, user_ids: [ 1, 9 ] },
  ]
});

test2.save(function(err, t2) { console.log("test", err, t2); });
```

The query to get all objects with a userId of 2 would look like:

```
Test.find({ "teams.user_ids": { $in: [2] }}, function(err, res) {
  console.log("query:", err, res);
});
```

Or in a more mongoose way of reassembling queries:

```
Test.find()
  .where('teams.user_ids')
  .in([2])
  .then(result => { console.log(result); })
  .catch(err => { console.log(err); });
```